# changing javascript function name or ID of element in HTML template makes it stop working

Tags: javascript, django

I am developing an app in Django.
I have this weird issue.

on my template I have:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input name="Data_inserimento_entry" type="date" class="form-control" id="date_to_turn_into_toda" >              
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/get_today_date.js" %}></script>
<script> get_today_date(date_to_turn_into_toda) </script>
```

on the js file `get_today_date.js` stored at **static > js > get_today_date.js** 
I have

```
function get_today_date(id_data) {
var now = new Date();
var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day);
document.getElementById(id_data).value = today;
}
```

when I run the server and load the template, in the input slot, today's date appears. I am glad of that.

If I comment any of the two javascript lines in the template, it does not work anymore. I am glad of that.

Here comes the weird part

If I change the id ,
like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input name="Data_inserimento_entry" type="date" class="form-control" id="date_to_turn_into_today" >              
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/get_today_date.js" %}></script>
<script> get_today_date(date_to_turn_into_today) </script>
```

It does not work anymore. Why?

And even if I change the function name in both scripts, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/get_today_date.js" %}></script>
<script> get_today_date_ID(date_to_turn_into_today) </script>
```

and

```
function get_today_date_ID(id_data) {
var now = new Date();
var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day);
document.getElementById(id_data).value = today;
}
```

It does not work anymore. Why?

Is the syntax to call javascript correct?

Am I forgetting to change the ID or the function name in some other place than the template and the javascript file?

*Note:* the function in the javascript file and the javascript file have the same name (except for the extention .js), is this the problem?

**Update:**

in my model, I have:

```
class mymodel(models.Model):

    Data_inserimento_entry = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False, default=timezone.now().date() )
```

**Update:**

here I post the whole template aggiungi_terminologia.html, responding to a comment asking for more explanation

```
    {% extends 'base.html'%} 

    {% block content %}

        <h1>Aggiungi terminologia in massa</h1>

        <!-- scarica template glossario -->


        <p>        
        <form method="get" action="static/files_for_download/template_glossario.xlsx">
        <div class="container"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Scarica template</button>
        </div>
        </form>
        </p>

        <div class="container">   
        <small id="inputHelp" class="form-text text-muted">NOTA: Non rinominare le colonne del template.</small>     
        </div>  


        <br>


        <!-- carica glossario -->
        <p>
        <form class="container" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="file-upload-wrapper" id="input-file-now">

                <small id="inputHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Seleziona il template compilato con la terminologia da caricare.</small>                  
                <input type="file"  name="uploaded_glossary" id="input-file-now" data-max-file-size="5M" class="file-upload">

                <br><br> 


                <div class="form-group">

                     <input name="Data_inserimento_entry" type="hidden" class="form-control" id="date_to_turn_into_toda">              
                </div>



                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Carica glossario</button>
            </div>

        </form>
        </p>


        <br><br><br><br>

    <!-- Django tag load static -->
    {% load static %}  

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static "css/searchbar_style.css" %}>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static "css/upload_glossary_slot.css" %}>

    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/get_today_date.js" %}></script>
    <script> get_today_date("date_to_turn_into_toda") </script> 


    {% endblock %}
```

Here I post my entire template base.html:

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- favicon -->
    <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'img/gestisco_logo_round_favicon2.png' %}" /> -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'img/metaglossary_favicon_3.png' %}" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>G</title>
  </head>
  <body>


      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">

        <!-- Pagina iniziale -->
        <!-- questa nel tutorial non c è -->


        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">GESTI.S.CO Interreg IT-CH</a> 
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                <!-- glossario -->
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'glossario' %}">Glossario<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

              </li>

              <!-- Aggiungi terminologia -->
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'aggiungi_terminologia' %}">Aggiungi terminologia</a>
              </li>

              <!-- Aggiungi glossario -->
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'aggiungi_glossario' %}">Aggiungi terminologia in massa</a>
              </li>





            </ul>


          </div>
        </nav>


        <br/>


<!-- SEZIONE MESSAGGI -->

        {% if messages %}

          {% for message in messages %}


            {% if insert_attempt_output == "errato" %}
            <!-- form compilato in modo NON valido - messaggio rosso -->

                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                        <small><sup>[X]</sup></small>
                    </button>
                    {{message}}
                  </div>            

            {% else %}            
            <!-- form compilato in modo valido - messaggio verde -->

            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                    <small><sup>[X]</sup></small>
                </button>
                {{message}}
              </div>  


            {% endif %}

          {% endfor %}

       {% endif %}

      <br> 

    <!-- formattazione del body -->

    <div class="container">



        {% block content %}



        {% endblock %}



      </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <!-- css -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static "css/top_navbar_style.css" %}>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache? Script files and Html pages tend to get cached and it may not have all of your changes.

Comment: it does not solve it. I tryed to close the window and open the website in another one, restarting the server... nothing :(

Answer (score 1):

> when I run the server and load the template, in the input slot, today's date appears. I am glad of that.

I have no idea how it could work, because it looks like the main problem you have is you pass variable into the function `get_today_date` instead of string (id), i.e. instead of

```
<script> get_today_date(date_to_turn_into_today) </script>
```

call

```
<script> get_today_date('date_to_turn_into_today') </script>
```

Comment: if I substitute <script> get_today_date(date_to_turn_into_toda) </script> with <script> get_today_date("date_to_turn_into_toda") </script> it still works. If I substitute <script> get_today_date("date_to_turn_into_toda") </script> with <script> get_today_date("date_to_turn_into_today") </script> and I also change the ID in the template <input name="Data_inserimento_entry" type="date" class="form-control" id="date_to_turn_into_today" >     It does not work anymore

Comment: post updated. in my model I have : Data_inserimento_glossary = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False, default=timezone.now().date() ) . You think this is also contributing to the problem?

Comment: @Tms91 hmm, how do you render your template? Can you post your whole template? Is there another field with the same name `date_to_turn_into_today`?

Comment: @Tms91 hm, you've changed your date field to `hidden` in the template you posted, but I guess that shouldn't matter. Isn't there another field in `base.html` that could interfere with your field?

Comment: I don't think so. anyway i posted the template base.html . post updated! thanks

Comment: @Tms91 tbh I can't see anything else wrong, try to refresh the page, e.g. with CTRL+F5 when you change your js file. And it's impossible to debug without additional error info (any errors in console?)